# template call seem to be unmatch

Tags: c++, templates

I have this program with 2 template functions :

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T> void assign(T& t1,T& t2){
    std::cout << "First method";
    t1=t2;
}
template <class T> void assign(T& t1,const T& t2) {
    std::cout << "Second method";
    t1=t2;
}
class A
{
public:
    A(int a):_a(a){};
private:
    int _a;
    friend A operator+(const A& l, const A& r);
};
A operator+(const A& l, const A& r) {
    return A(l._a+r._a);
}
int main ()
{
    A a=1;
    const A b=2;
    assign(a,a+b);
}
```

i cant understand why does the `assign(a,a+b)` call the second template function 
, in the `operator+` we are createing a new `A` object and call the ctor with an int parameter.

it is creating `a+b` as const object ?

Comment: non-const lvalue refs don't bind to temporaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is creating a+b as const object ?

No, it is creating a temporary. Temporaries are binded to rvalue references. You can verify that with a 'third' function (a universal reference, in this case)

```
template <class T> 
void assign(T& t1, T&& t2) {
    std::cout << "Third method";
    t1=t2;
}
```

As you don't have one, the compiler will pick the const reference overload. Why ?

Suppose you have

```
void add(int & x)
{
    ++x;
}
unsigned y = 0;
add(y); // create a temporary to int
std::cout << y << "\n"; // what's the value of y  ?
```